# highstock.js chart plotting is a bit off

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highstock.js to represent a chart. The problem is that the plotting is showing values little to the right of the actual date on x-axis. The date in the legend matches to the date on x-axis. But the plotting is a bit to the right of that date when zoomed.

please check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HL7jX/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            //type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: "Weekly Managed Product Fund Flows",
            margin:50
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0,
            align: "left",
            buttons: [
                    {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'},
                     {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3m'},
                     {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'},
                    ]
        },
        navigator: {
            height: 10
        },
        xAxis: {  
             type:'datetime',
             maxZoom: 24 * 3600000,
             alignTicks : false
        },
        yAxis:[{ 
            title: {
                text: 'Flow US$ mill'
            }
        }, { 
            title: {
                text: 'AMZ'
            },
             labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        exporting: {
                enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
                enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            align: "top",
            layout: "horizontal",
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            x:250,
            y:-150
            /*labelFormatter: function() {
                return this.name + ' (T)';
            }*/

        },
       plotOptions:{
            series:{
                     stacking: 'normal'
            },
            line:{
                marker: {
                    symbol:"circle",
                    enabled: true
                }
           }
        },
        series: [/*{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Total Flows',
            data: all,
            tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },*/{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Mutual Fund Flows',
            data: mf,
            tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'ETF Flows',
            data: etf,
            tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            name:'Alerian AMZ Index',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: AMZ_YTD,
            tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Could you add sample data? Also, check [useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apepars to be a matter of the timestanp passed.

For example: The AMZ Index series, for June 13th - your time stamp is 1371097800000.
This converts to Thu Jun 13 2013 00:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)

The tick is set for midnight, the data point value is a half hour later.

If you want the points to match up exactly, make sure the timestamps are set for midnight.

You can also set useUTC false to avoid issues with timezones.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC